Help to identify artist and the message (Characters identified: 梅幸 扇舍)

We recently were going through a relatives belongings and we came across this beautiful painting wrapped in handmade paper, can anyone help translate any of the symbols or point us to where we could find out?

I've asked this on 百度知道. Both 2 answers agree that the words are: 梅幸 扇舍, but nobody knows the meaning. I personally think they are names.

I saw this entry on Wikipedia, which contains the two keywords mentioned in the question: 尾上梅幸 (6代目).

六代目 尾上梅幸（ろくだいめ おのえ ばいこう、明治3年（1870年）10月15日（新暦11月8日）～昭和9年（1934年）11月8日）は、歌舞伎役者。屋号は音羽屋、定紋は重ね扇に抱き柏、替紋は四ツ輪。本名は、寺島 栄之助（てらじま えいのすけ）。


「扇舍閑談」（『名優藝談』所収）川尻清潭編　中央公論社　昭和11年（1936年）

Maybe it's related to the topic.
